# highlight entire row using conditional format

Tags: excel

I reviewed below answer. it's really working for me when i used david's answer. But i have slight different question.

I want to highlight A1,B1,C1,D1 and E1 when condition is true for A1. As per the below answer it highlighting only values in column A

[Compare Two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008678/excel-compare-two-columns-and-highlight-when-found)

Regards,
Ramana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you should highlight columns `A:E` in case `A1` has "abc" value, you should do the following:

1. Select the desired range of cells (or perhaps entire columns `A:E`).
2. Add Conditional Formatting rule based on a formula, enter the following code: `=IF($A1="abc",1,0)=1`
3. Select desired highlight and apply rule.

You're done. The above code will highlight ANY row for `A:E` columns in case corresponding cell in A has "abc". Modify condition as you wish.

Sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/eyx2un2v5r5z25w/CondFormatA-E.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this formula for column A

`=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,$B:$B,1,FALSE)))`

then just amend it by putting $ in front of A1, i.e.

`=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A1,$B:$B,1,FALSE)))`

and apply that conditional format to all 5 columns A to E

Note: it might be simpler to use MATCH - this should give the same result

`=MATCH($A1,$B:$B,0)`

Comment: I am using vloop. As you said using match is the best option. i was forgot make column absolute for A1. Thanks a lot Hourdini for you help.