# Excel: if duplicate cell value found in another column then highlight green

Tags: excel, formatting, duplicates, conditional-statements, cell

Can someone help me, I'm not sure what formula to use.

I have highlighted the cell in the picture to show an example of what I mean.

What I want to do is highlight the cell in column A where the value matches a value in column D, it does not have to be in the same row. If there is a duplicate value in column D then highlight the cell in column A green.
[image]
Thanks for any help given.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel compare two columns and highlight when found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008678/excel-compare-two-columns-and-highlight-when-found)

Answer (score 3):

Try this as the conditional format formula

```
=MATCH(A1,$D:$D,0)
```