# Using =MATCH in reverse. About previous answer

Tags: excel, match

In response to: [Excel: if duplicate cell value found in another column then highlight green](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559207/excel-if-duplicate-cell-value-found-in-another-column-then-highlight-green)

If I want to also reverse this to have items in the right column to highlight if they are not in the left column, how can I do this.

** With ICEARDOR's answer I was able to get it but it highlights the entire column. Anyway to get it to only highlight when text is entered.**

Comment: Actually they both work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the conditional formatting equation `=isna(MATCH(D1,$A:$A,0))` to column D.

Comment: Its highlighting the entire column. Is there a way to only have it highlight only when text is entered?